# Use awk to get two specific columns from third line of file based on value in first line

Tags: awk

I'm looking to conditionally select two columns from the third line of a file based on the first column of the first line of the file.

Here is the file format:

```
v1
shortdesc
value1 value2 value3 value4 ...
```

Using this example, I'd want `value2` and `value3` if `v1`, otherwise, I'd like `value1` and `value4`.

I know how to get the line and column using something like `awk 'FNR ==1 {print $1}` but how do I use the `if` clause?

The code that is not working for me looks something like this:

```
awk '{if("NR == 1 $1"=="v1") {FNR==3 print $2 "\t" $3;} else {FNR==3 print $1 "\t" $4;}}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
awk 'NR == 1 { if ($1 == "v1") { p = 1; } } NR == 3 { if (p) { print $2 "\t" $3; } else { print $1 "\t" $4; } }' file
```

Comment: `awk 'NR==1{a=$1}NR==3{if(a=="v1")print $2,$3;else print $1,$4;exit}' OFS='\t' file`

Comment: @Costas post it as answer.

Comment: it is just variant of yours with some extra `{}` removed

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:
**sed**

```
sed -n '1h
        3{
            x
            G
            s/v1\n\S* \(\S* \S*\).*/\1/p
            t
            s/.*\n\(\S*\) \S* \S*\( \S*\).*/\1\2/p
          }
         4Q' file
```

**test**, **head**, **tail**, **cut**

```
[ $(head -1 file) == 'v1' ] &&
    field='2,3' ||
    field='1,4'
head -5 file | tail -1 | cut -d" " -f"$field"
```

**bash**

```
{ read v1
  read
  read a b c d e
  } <file
[ "$v1" == 'v1' ] && echo $b $c || echo $a $d
```